# Can I use android SpeechRecognition in a Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, kindle-fire

I have been using the speech recognition provides by Google in my android app, but when I try test it in a Kindle Fire, crash.
Debugging I found that it was my fault because forgot check if recognition was available before start the service.

```
//Mental note: Check always the service before start it
if(SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
    ...
}else{
    //Show a AlertDialog with the advise
}
```

With this check I discovered that Amazon didn't bring a speech recognition service ([by now](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=5075&#5075)). After make a few Google search, I found [this topic](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1174) in Amazon developers forum with a similar question. Amazon answer was **"Not now"** but **"Stay tuned in our blog"**. Finally the guy has integrated with *Dragon Mobile SDK* and it's work for him. I'm not interested in integrate another SDK (third part reason) but I would like to know if anyone found a "workaround" like install Google Apps or something while Amazon provides something.

Anyway if you are looking for some info about this, I hope this question bring you some light... :)

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have tried to add Google Play Services with this [How to](http://androidcowboy.com/2013/10/add-google-account-kindle-fire-hdx/), but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2013/03/speech-recognition-on-kindle-touch-with-cmusphinx/

Comment: Thanks, but to use this must have KUAL and I can't jailbreak or root the device.

Comment: For pocketsphinx on Android see http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: Thanks, @NikolayShmyrev. I couldn't find it from the first link. It seems there is no way to reuse the android speech recognition so I will have to make a new implementation for Kindle case...

Comment: Ok, it should be straightforward. Feel free to ask on Sourceforge forums if you have troubles.